# Web scraping - challenges articulating hierarchy in my code

Tags: python, html, web-scraping, beautifulsoup

**Objective:**
I am trying to scrape a 100s of web pages, specifically the ingredients for the recipe on each. If we take an example -  which contains the recipe for an Egg Sandwich ([url](https://www.simplyrecipes.com/recipes/egg_salad_sandwich/)) for which I'm using many Python dependencies including `BeautifulSoup`, `splinter.Browser`, `ChromeDrivermanager`.
**Expected output:**
Once I have scraped the ingredients, I would like to save them in a dictionary. Example below -

```
recipes = {"quick_and_easy_egg_salad_sandwich_recipe":
['1-2 tablespoons mayonnaise (to taste)',
 '2 tablespoons chopped celery',
 '2 slices white, wheat, multigrain, or rye bread, toasted or plain']
```

**What I've achieved:**
1. I have been able to determine 'roughly' (through Web Inspector) what I need to focus on -
[image]
It looks like each ingredient has it's own `<li class='ingredient'>` however it looks like I have either misinterpreted the hierarchy or my code is incorrect.

2.My code is as follows -

```
executable_path = {'executable_path': ChromeDriverManager().install()}
browser = Browser('chrome', **executable_path)

webpage_url = 'https://www.simplyrecipes.com/recipes/egg_salad_sandwich/'
browser.visit(webpage_url)
time.sleep(1)
website_html = browser.html
website_soup = BeautifulSoup(website_html, 'html.parser')
ingredients = website_soup.find('h3', class_="Ingredients")
ingredientsList = ingredients.find('li', class_ = "ingredient")
print({ingredients})
```

When I attempt to print `{ingredients}` I get a `AttributeError: 'NoneType' object has no attribute 'find'`
I know my code is flawed, however I just don't know how to approach this and wondered if anyone has any suggestions?

Comment: Just curious, why using splinter?

Comment: h3 element doesn't have a class `Ingredients`. so, this is wrong `ingredients = website_soup.find('h3', class_="Ingredients")`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

try this,

```
import requests
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup

resp = requests.get("https://www.simplyrecipes.com/recipes/egg_salad_sandwich/")

soup = BeautifulSoup(resp.text, "html.parser")
div_ = soup.find("div", attrs={"class": "recipe-callout"})

recipes = {"_".join(div_.find("h2").text.split()):
               [x.text for x in div_.findAll("li", attrs={"class": "ingredient"})]}
```

Answer (score 0):

It sounds like your code should be below, after I removed unnecessary `h3` retrieval

```
executable_path = {'executable_path': ChromeDriverManager().install()}
browser = Browser('chrome', **executable_path)

webpage_url = 'https://www.simplyrecipes.com/recipes/egg_salad_sandwich/'
browser.visit(webpage_url)
time.sleep(1)
website_html = browser.html
website_soup = BeautifulSoup(website_html, 'html.parser')
ingredientsList = website_soup.find('li', class_ = "ingredient")
print({ingredients})
```

You were trying to find `h3` element with `Ingredients` as class name, which doesn't exist